# Is Curve25519 better option than Secp256k1?

Tags: signature, ecdsa, secp256k1, schnorr-signatures

Are signatures over Curve25519 better than over Secp256k1 or are there major drawbacks?

How do, for instance, EdDSA/Schnorr using Curve25519 compare with ECDSA/Schnorr for Secp256k1?

Comment: I do prefer the new phrasing, but you could have just edited the prior post instead of creating a new question. :)

Comment: Okay  I just thought it would be better this way